# How to quit Menu Item mode in the info command page

Tags: info

I am using `info` command, and when I press <kbd>m</kbd>, the keyboard prompt goes into a `menu item:` mode and I don't know how to quit from this mode. I tried <kbd>q</kbd> and <kbd>ESC</kbd>, but it didn't work.

Finally, I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to quit. Is there any decent way to quit the `menu item:` prompt mode in the "info" command?

Comment: A quick test with `info` here tells me that pressing Enter a few times works.

Comment: Yes, you are correct...thanks for answering my question.

Comment: Added it as an answer; please mark it as solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick test with `info` here tells me that pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> one time works.

Comment: A few times? One time is enough, for me.

Comment: I have edited it to "One Time"

Answer (score 3):

Info is a standalone program that mimics Emacs's built-in documentation interface. Emacs does not come from the unix world, and some of its key bindings are different from the traditional unix bindings. In particular, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is the back-to-toplevel key under unix, but under Emacs, that's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> (which is also the bell character when it is emitted by the terminal). So press **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>** at the `Menu item:` prompt. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> exits Info because what it does in Emacs (customizable prefix) is not applicable to Info so Info gives it a unix meaning instead (kill the current program).

Comment: Very insightful knowledge indeed although I don't quite understand those terms, but thank you for providing more useful information to the questions.